# Qt Arm Remote Debugging

Tags: qt, arm, remote-debugging, codesourcery, eabi

I am working on LPC1768. I want to debug test_ram.elf file using arm-none-eabi-gdb on qt creator. 
I downloaded code to test from http://www.yagarto.de/download/yagarto/LPC1768Test.zip

Unfortunetely, I couldn’t handle remote debugging. I want to debug using j-link gdbserver.

I tried Debug->Start Debugging->Attach to Remote debug server
And

```
Start Debugger Settings
Debugger : C:\Program Files\CodeSourcery\Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI\bin\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe
Local Executable : C:\Users\asd\qtprojects\pr2\test_ram.elf
Host and Port : localhost:2331
Architecture : arm
GNU : auto
Sysroot : 
Location of debugging information :
Override host GDB start script : C:\Users\asd\qtprojects\pr2\prj\lpc17xx_flash_jlink_1.gdb
```

I got this warning after doing settings above :

> The preferred debugger engine for debugging binaries of type ‘unknown-unknown-unknown-unknown-unknown’ is not available. The debugger engine ‘Gdb engine’ will be used as a fallback. Details: The CDB debug engine does not support the unknown-unknown-unknown-unknown-unknown ABI.

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that debugger you are using is default one (x86). For debugging arm (LPC in your case) you need different debugger(CodeSourcery).

You need to enable Bare Metal plugin and restart Qt creator.Go to options and add a new bare metal device. After that you need to add a kit for CodeSourcery. Add CodeSourcery compiler and debugger in Qt creator option. After that add a new kit and select the added tools. Then launch the project you want to debug with new kit.

For more information [What is Qt Bare Metal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434280/what-is-qt-bare-metal)